# Pass value to imported script in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-3.5

I have to Python scripts. In the first script I import the second script and need to pass a value to the second script.
I tried the following:
**test1.py:**

```
import test2

test2.set_value(5)
test2.print_value()
```

**test2.py:**

```
value = None

def set_value(v):
    print("Set value: " + str(v))
    value = v

def print_value():
    print(value)
```

But the output is:

> Set value: 5 
>   None

I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: `value` is local to `set_value`, you're not touching `value` in the global scope. Use `global` to do so.

Comment: while `global` would fix your issue, it's usually highly recommended that you don't use `global`; rather you should pass value in to the function: `def print_value(value)`

Comment: Thanks, I did'nt know about the global statement! @MooingRawr: I don't need to the script to print the function. I definitely need the value in the second script.

Comment: @no0by5 regardless of what you are doing with the value, you should be passing values into functions if the function needs to use those 'values'. Using `global` would get messy once your project becomes larger, it's not really a practical practice for scalability.